# nswag command line generating proxy file not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, nswag, nswagstudio

I have used NSwagStudio to generate client proxy in c#. I saved the project into an .nswag file. I have added it to my .net core console app. I then use the following command in package manager console
`nswag.cmd run .\client.nswag /runtime:NetCore31`

I get

```
NSwag command line tool for .NET Core NetCore31, toolchain v13.7.4.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.26.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))
Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
NSwag bin directory: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nswag\bin\binaries\NetCore31

Executing file '.\client.nswag' with variables ''...
Done.
```

But I dont see the output file created. Where is this file saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the output file by either:

- Giving a value to `output` variable in `nswag.json`: `"output": "<your_path>/client.cs"`
- Passing it as a parameter to your cli* invocation: `nswag.cmd run .\client.nswag /runtime:NetCore31 /output:<your_path>/client.cs`

* The same applies to [`NSwag.MSBuild`](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag.MSBuild), in case you ever go down that path:

`$(NSwagExe_Core31) run .\client.nswag /runtime:NetCore31 /output:<your_path>/client.cs`

Comment: And for mac? I can't get any command line arguments to work